# Identifier expected in connection string

Tags: vb.net

I get connection string from app config .But it gives a error when trying to get the connection string . Here is the code.

```
 str = Convert.ToString(Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: why do you need a Convert.ToString

Comment: Convert a string to a string? Also what's the error?

Comment: because  it gives an other error "Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString " cannot convert to string

Comment: Is there an a connection string in your config called "MyConnection"? Are you accessing it from the right location? If this is VB.Net why is there a ';' at the end of the line?

Comment: it's mistake i  deleted it. still i get this error

Answer (score 0):

[Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6t3b6f3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) (or arays) in VB.NET have round brackets instead of square bracket as in C#, so this works:

```
Dim conStr As String = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Myconnection").ConnectionString
```

Note that `ConnectionString` returns already a `String`, so you don't need to use `Convert.ToString`, you also have to remove the semicolon at the end.